# EF 6.0 Code First: Multiplicity constraint violated. the role of the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

Many people already asked almost similar question but I could figure out my issue from those questions and andswers. So here is my issue

**What I want:**

Insert and Update of different instances of same entity type in one go.

**What I did:**

*My Entity:*

```
public partial class Record
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    .....
    .....
}
```

*What I tried:*

What below function will be doing is that it will update the passing client and make a deep copy out of it and try to save as fresh copy.

```
private void CreateRecord(Record data)
{
     // Update
     _dbSet.Attached(data);  /*OR*/ // _dbSet.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;   

    // Insert Copy
    var newData= data.DeepCopy(); // DeepCopy is custom extension function
    newData.Id = 0;
    _dbSet.Add(newData);

    context.SaveChanges();
}

// Invoking above function

CreateRecord(new Record(){Name="xyz", Id =123 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to got your question right, your solution doesn't work right?

First of all could you add your DeepCopy() function to your question?

Try to change the state of your updated entity as well (both, not like in your solution "OR"):

```
Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Another solution would be:

```
private void CreateRecord(Record data)
{
     // Update
     _dbSet.Attached(data); 
     context.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;   

    // Insert Copy
    var newData = new Record();
    newData.Name = data.Name;
    _dbSet.Add(newData);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

ID will be added automatically by the framework/database, because it's the primary key. Because of it's name ("id") it will be auto incremented and unique.

Comment: you could modify your DeepCopy() so that it only copies the non primary properties.

Comment: Thanks @Olli1511 I also tried the way you suggest, using Attached and Changing state but didn't work unluckily :(  About DeepCopy() I just trying to convey a message that insert new instance but have same info. I tried creating an instance and manually assign the properties. Even that also doesn't work.